# String in syslog when livepatch does something

Tags: kernel, logs, canonical-livepatch

I've subscribed to Canonical `livepatch` and I'm curious to know if it's ever actually done anything. By perusing syslogs I see the many times it checks for an update each day, always with the result

`No updates available at this time`

Does anyone know what string would be in the syslog if an update **were** available?  I'd like to grep for it to see if this has ever happened.

Comment: What is the total line of the `syslog` entry?

Comment: After the date/time/hostname entries, it's just `canonical-livepatch[1530]: No updates available at this time.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see where there was an entry that didn't include **No updates** run this.  That will show you the entries of the available updates.

```
$ egrep "canonical-livepatch" /var/log/syslog | egrep -v "No .*(updates|payloads).* available at this time"
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it's worse than I made it sound.  Each check produces 3 lines of output "Checking with livepatch service", "No updates available at this time", "No payload available".  And it checks once per hour.  I imagine your script will produce the other 2 lines.  I could just do a giant grep of canonical-livepatch and sort the result, but I was hoping someone would know.

Comment: @OrganicMarble You're welcome!  It's a pleasure.  I edited my answer to take in the new information you provided.    If you were seeing 3 lines before, you'll now see two lines.  If you tell me what is in the two lines you see I can adjust it down to 0 until there are updates.

Comment: What you have there works well AFAICT, returning no results, so apparently I've never been livepatched.  Thanks!